# Swift Package Manager reverts to https from when fetching associated packages

Tags: swift, xcode

Im trying to add the firebase package `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk` to my project. So i go to `Project > Package Dependencies > +` search for `git@github.com:firebase/firebase-ios-sdk` intentionally not using the `https` url. Then select add.

It starts fine but then i can see it fetching the associated packages and they are all prefixed `https` not `ssh` or `git@` etc. Then the process fails.

[image]

Ive set my global and local `.gitconfig` to

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

ive also gone to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` selected my github account and set the `Clone using` option to `ssh`

finally i have the following in my `.ssh/config` file

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Is there anything else i can do or that ive missed so that i can use ssh with swift package manager?

Answer (score 0):

So, removing

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

from the global and local config files then running `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
resolved this issue for me :)